# Solidity HardHat testing NFT transfer

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I'd like to test the deployment, minting and transfer of an NFT in hardhat.

Here's my test code:

```
describe("Receiving NFT", function () {
    it("Should emit a received NFT event", async function () {
      const { bridge, owner, otherAccount } = await loadFixture(deployFixture);
      const { token, owner: tokenContractOwner } = await loadFixture(deployMockNFTFixture);

      await token.connect(otherAccount.address)
      await token.mint(otherAccount.address)
      console.log(await token.balanceOf(otherAccount.address));
      console.log(await token.ownerOf(1));

      console.log("bridge.target: ", bridge.target)
      console.log("owner.address: ", owner.address)

      await token.connect(otherAccount.address)
      await token.transferFrom(otherAccount.address, bridge.target, 1);
      
      console.log(await token.balanceOf(bridge.target));
      console.log(await token.ownerOf(1));

      // console.log(await token.ownerOf(1));
      // await expect() 
      // .to.emit(bridge, "ReceivedNFT");
      // .withArgs(lockedAmount, anyValue);
    })
  })
})
```

The `transferFrom` line fails with error: `Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'ERC721: caller is not token owner or approved'`

I added logs in the code and these are the logs:

```
1n
otherAccount.address: 0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8
bridge.target:  0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3
owner.address:  0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266
msg.sender:  0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266
```

The msg.sender of when `transferFrom` is executed is the owner.address of the owner who deployed both the contracts. Even though I use `await token.connect(otherAccount.address)` to switch the `msg.sender` to the otherAccount.

How do I execute the transferFrom from the otherAccount ?

I've minted the NFT to the otherAccount and need to transfer it to the bridge contract. Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I've added an approval step:

```
await token.connect(otherAccount.address)
await token.approve(bridge.target, 1)
await token.transferFrom(otherAccount.address, bridge.target, 1);
```

However, I still get an error which is:
`Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'ERC721: approve caller is not token owner or approved for all'`

For some reason, the msg.sender is `0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266`, the contract deployer, despite doing token.connect(otherAccount.address)...

Comment: The person who is calling the transfer does not own the token, nor are they approved to transfer it

Comment: If you want someone else to transfer it, the token owner, must call approve on the contract executing the transfer for that specific token id

Comment: even after approval, I get an error `Error: no matching fragment (operation="fragment", info={ "args": [ "0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3" ], "key": "approve" }, code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.7.1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that despite doing a `.connect` to change the msg.sender to the otherAccount, Hardhat was still showing the msg.sender as the owner.address (the address that deployed both contracts), so as a workaround, I minted the nft from the owner address and approved and transfered from the owner address and the test worked.

```
it("Should emit a received NFT event", async function () {
      const { bridge, owner } = await loadFixture(deployFixture);
      const { token } = await loadFixture(deployMockNFTFixture);

      // await token.connect(otherAccount.address)
      await token.mint(owner.address)
      console.log(await token.balanceOf(owner.address));
      console.log(await token.ownerOf(1));

      console.log("bridge.target: ", bridge.target)
      console.log("owner.address: ", owner.address)

      // await token.connect(otherAccount.address)
      await token.approve(bridge.target, 1)

      
      console.log(await token.balanceOf(bridge.target));
      console.log(await token.ownerOf(1));

      expect(await token.transferFrom(owner.address, bridge.target, 1)) 
      .to.emit(bridge, "ReceivedNFT");
    })
```